# sudo: aws: command not found

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Installed aws cli 2 on my Centos machine. Added

> PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"

to `/etc/environment`. Most of the cases aws command can be called successfully. However, when using `sudo aws`, it shows command not found. Below are all the scenarios. Any idea?

```sh
[centos@ip-172-20-x-x ~]$ aws --version
aws-cli/2.1.28 Python/3.8.8 Linux/3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64 exe/x86_64.centos.7 prompt/off
[centos@ip-172-20-x-x ~]$ sudo su
[root@ip-172-20-x-x centos]# aws --version
aws-cli/2.1.28 Python/3.8.8 Linux/3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64 exe/x86_64.centos.7 prompt/off
[root@ip-172-20-x-x centos]# sudo aws --version
sudo: aws: command not found
[root@ip-172-20-x-x centos]# cat /etc/environment
PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"
[root@ip-172-20-x-x centos]# sudo env
HOSTNAME=ip-172-20-x-x.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
TERM=xterm
HISTSIZE=1000
USERNAME=root
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/centos
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
LOGNAME=root
USER=root
HOME=/root
SHELL=/bin/bash
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/env
SUDO_USER=root
SUDO_UID=0
SUDO_GID=0
XDG_SESSION_ID=20
```

Comment: So where is the awscli actually installed?

Comment: the trouble is the path where `aws cli` is installed , is not available in `root` user's path.

Comment: Why do you need to run the awscli as root?

Comment: And where **is** it installed to?  `which aws` as the user that gets output from it ....

Comment: awscli installed under /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you installed the CLI, and why do you need sudo for `aws cli`.

Assuming you have sudo privileges on the machine, can install using the below command, from the post I can see you already have `/usr/local/bin` already in the root path.

> The installation command uses a file named install in the newly unzipped aws directory. By default, the files are all installed to /usr/local/aws-cli, and a symbolic link is created in /usr/local/bin. The command includes sudo to grant write permissions to those directories

```sh
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

Alternately you can simply update the `root` path with the `aws cli` path available for `centos` non root-user.

To find out the path for aws cli you can use `which` command

```
$ which aws
/usr/local/bin/aws
```

```
export PATH=<AWS CLI PATH>:$PATH
```

[Installing, updating, and uninstalling the AWS CLI version 2 on Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html)

Comment: If I type which aws, it shows installed under /usr/local/bin/aws. No matter which account I logged in, I can see /usr/local/bin added the PATH variable. So I suppose running sudo aws can call awscli without any problem. I still dont understand why login as root I can run awscli without problem, but if running sudo aws it gives me an error.

Comment: And I used sudo aws sometimes for copying file from S3 to local folder which only allow access for root.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, install `awscli` correctly using `pip`: you may have installed it with `apt` ,but although the `awscli` package is available in repositories for other package managers such as `apt` and `yum`, ***these are NOT produced, managed, or supported by AWS***.
So, if u didn't installed with pip, try reinstalling `awscli` as follows:

```
sudo pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade
```

Otherwise, if you have ***installed `awscli` using the bundled installer without sudo***, you must know that this installs the `AWS CLI` to the default location `(~/.local/lib/aws)` and creates a symbolic link (symlink) at `~/bin/aws`. Make sure that `~/bin` is in your `PATH` environment variable for the symlink to work, as follows:

```
$ echo $PATH | grep ~/bin     // See if $PATH contains ~/bin (output will be empty if it doesn't)
$ export PATH=~/bin:$PATH     // Add ~/bin to $PATH if necessary
```

For any doubt, visit the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html).

Comment: This answer solves the issue when awscli is installed in a virtual environment, e.g. conda, poetry. Essentially just make sure both `$(which aws)` and its one-level-up path are in `PATH`.